# Does Chrome DevTools show what cert was used on a given GET or POST request

Tags: google-chrome, postman, certificate, x509certificate

#### Description of Problem

I'm trying to hit a REST endpoint that requires a certificate from the browser and from Postman.

I've configured Chrome and Postman with a client side cert.  The cert works when using a Chrome on a Swagger page (using the *client side cert* selected by a browser popup) but not when using Postman.

So my guess is that Postman is not using the certificate I've configured.  I tried to examine Chrome DevTools Networking tab to see if it shows the certificate being passed, but it doesn't.

So that is my question.  **Does Chrome (or Postman) have the ability to display the client side certificate being used for a given request?**

I'm looking for something akin to using the `curl --verbose` with a client side certificate.   When using `--verbose` with curl, both the client and server side certificate information is dumped to the console for viewing.

**Does Chrome DevTools (or Postman) support something like this?**

#### Searching for an answer to my question

Searching in SO for [[certificate and debugging]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcertificate%5D%20debugging)  and [[certificate and google-chrome]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/certificate+google-chrome) and [[certificate and postman]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/certificate+postman) I found:

- [Testing API's with certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69744418/testing-apis-with-certificates) - This was helpful but didn't answer my question
- [How to determine if server has ssl certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51985767/how-to-determine-if-server-has-ssl-certificate) - did not help
- [need help Debugging SSL handshake in tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8436138/need-help-debugging-ssl-handshake-in-tomcat) - Useful but not applicable for my question
- [Created self signed Certificate working with curl but not with chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67690550/created-self-signed-certificate-working-with-curl-but-not-with-chrome) - Did not help
- Many other certificate questions so *maybe* the answer is there.  If so please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I found that *Postman*  when it's using certificates, it includes a Networking section in the Postman Console output.

For example,

```
GET https://example.com//api/my/restEndpoint
401
11 ms
Warning: Unable to verify the first certificate
Network
addresses: {…}
local: {…}
remote: {…}
tls: {…}
reused: false
authorized: false
authorizationError: "UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE"
cipher: {…}
protocol: "TLSv1.3"
ephemeralKeyInfo: {}
peerCertificate: {…}
```

This shows that the certificate was not trusted (e.g., the certificate authority was not known).